# Passing unmanaged array to a Managed Thread. - memory corruption

Tags: multithreading, heap-memory, unmanaged, managed, heap-corruption

I'm a newbie for .Net and trying to use managed threading.
I couldn't find any problem in my code, but it triggers an exception when the Thread Ends.
Something like:
Unhandled exception at 0x5cbf80ea (msvcr90d.dll)
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000d7.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

#define sz 100

//int dt[sz]; //allcating a gloal buffer
int *dt;


void workerThread (void)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Producer Thread Started!");
    int data = 50;
    for(int i=0; i<sz; i++)
    {
        Thread::Sleep(1);
        dt[i] = i;
        Console::WriteLine("Producer W={0}", i);
    };
    Console::WriteLine("Producer Thread Ending");
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine("This is a test on global variable and threading");
    //allcating a buffer
    dt = new int(sz);

    Thread ^wthrd = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&workerThread));
    //Starting Worker Thread..
    wthrd->Start(); 
    //Waiting for Worker Thread to end.
    wthrd->Join();  
    Console::WriteLine("Worker Thread Ended.");
    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

However it works fine when I allocate the buffer as a global array. This exception kicks in when I use "new" keyword, hence a  dynamic memory allocation.
Am I making any fundamental mistakes?
Is this something to deal with the garbage collector? or Unmanaged heap allocated by the "new" keyword?
I would really prefer to have this buffer in unmanaged heap. Although I am writing a managed code, many other DLLs I am using are unmanaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt = new int(sz);
```

This is allocating a *single* integer, (**not** an array), and initializing it with the value of `sz` (100).  What you want is this:

```
dt = new int[sz];
```

This allocates an *array* of size `dt`.  Note that in order to avoid leaking memory, you must later free it like this:

```
delete [] dt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really an elementary mistake.

The debugger doesn't complain about the mistake until the thread tries to end. VS debugger is not aware of these kind of situations? I'm surprised that the debugger not handling this well.